# I keep getting a Timestamp Type error message

Tags: python

```
df2 = df2.loc[(df2['timestamp'] >= sd)
                       & (df2['timestamp'] <= ed)]
```

I used this code, but I keep getting this error. Can someone fix it?

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'datetime.datetime'

Answer (score 0):

This means that either column `timestamp` is not a `datetime` or `sd` or `ed` is not in the right format for implicit comparison. To fix, either convert to datetime first like so:

```
# convert to datetime
df2.loc[:,'timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df2.loc[:,'timestamp'])
```

or

```
ed = pd.to_datetime(ed)
sd = pd.to_datetime(sd)
```

or make sure that `sd` and `ed` are in the standard format akin to 'yyyy-mm-dd'

Two side notes. When you do the subset,  make sure you add `.copy()` otherwise you'll keep getting errors later. Second, with datetime, you can also use `between` to subset date intervals:

`df2.loc[df2.timestamp.between(sd,ed),:]`